# URI 1848 solution

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define endl '\n'

using namespace std;

int main() {

  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);

  string line;

  int acc = 0;

  while (cin >> line) {

    if (line == "caw") {

      cin >> line;

      cout << acc << endl;

      acc = 0;

    } else {

      int val = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

        val <<= 1;

        val += line[i] == '*';

      }
      acc += val;

    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

I came across this solution

can anyone please explain what does this val += line[i] == " * "; means?

*Please help!!!!*

Comment: `#define endl '\n'`, `using namespace std;` o.O???

Comment: First of all, don't blindly copy-paste or otherwise use sources you find on the Internet, not without actually knowing what they do. Secondly, it's a bad program and the inclusion of `<bits/stdc++.h>` is a clear indicator of it (see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) for more information). Thirdly, the program is *really* bad because it uses a macro `endl` which just happens to be the same as `std::endl` that prints a newline and flushes the output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Technically the program behaviour is *undefined* because of this redefinition.

Comment: Sure sir i wont blindly copy-paste code from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val += line[i] == " * ";` is evaluated as `val += (line[i] == " * ");` due to *operator precedence*.

`val` will be incremented by 1 (`true` converts to an integral value of 1) if, and only if, `line[i]` compares `true` with `" * "`, else it will stay the same.

Finally `#define endl '\n'` is *very* naughty. Don't attempt to change symbols in the C++ standard library.